# Is 2 hours enough for a connecting flight at EWR? Doing BOG-EWR-BER (Terminal B to C)

Tags: layovers, short-connections, connecting-flights, ewr

I'm doing BOG-EWR-BER on a single ticket with a 2h 20m layover at Newark (travelling with United Airlines). Since I'm an international arriving passenger, I will need to claim and recheck my bags, as well as go through customs and security. I'll also need to change from terminal B to C.

Will the 2h 20m layover be enough? I'm not quite sure about the procedure for arriving from abroad. What will I need to do?

PS: I have a B1/B2 visa.

Answer (score 6):

If you're on a single ticket, the airline thinks you can make this connection. If the connection fails, the airline must get you on a subsequent flight to your destination, and put you up in a hotel if the subsequent flight is the next day.

Thus, if you have a single ticket, and the arriving flight is on time, and you're not seated in the back row of the arriving aircraft, and there's no significant delay at baggage claim, and there's no significant delay at US Immigration...you're probably OK. And you'll be cared-for if the connection fails.

If, on the other hand, this is not a single ticket, and/or the arriving flight is delayed, and/or you're in the back row of the arriving plane, and/or there's a significant delay at baggage claim, and/or there's a big line at US Immigration (as happens, for example, when several international flights arrive near the same time), then you could well not make this connection.

The results of missing the connection will be significant if you are flying on two separate tickets: if you miss the outgoing flight EWR > BER, neither the first flight carrier nor the second flight carrier has any duty to provide you onward transportation to your destination, nor to provide support while you're stuck in Newark. Worse, if your outgoing flight is the first leg of a round-trip (EWR > BER > EWR), that airline will cancel the BER > EWR segment. Last-minute ticket purchases are always much more expensive than buying in advance.

If flying on two tickets, I wouldn't take the risk of this short connection. Your risk tolerance, however, may be calibrated differently than mine.

Comment: I was on Srilankan with a very short connection. I was asked by head flight attendant to come forward towards the end of the flight. I was escorted by the staff and through all procedures and my aircraft was waiting for me. I was the only person in that connection.

Comment: @Anish Sheela Was that making the same connection that the OP is asking about?

Comment: I was sharing an anecdote to show that Airline will make every reasonable step possible to make the connection, if its their responsibility. Otherwise, tough luck.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is on one ticket this should be fine unless you have really bad luck. In EWR you will have to clear immigration, customs and security. Customs is typically a non-event. You can check immigration wait times at https://awt.cbp.gov/  TSA wait times using an app https://www.tsa.gov/mobile

Having no checked luggage, high class of service, status with the airline, Global Entry, and/or TSA PreCheck all help to make things go faster. Without checked Luggage, Global Entry and Precheck, I have no problem making a 45 minute connection at Newark.

No connection is ever guaranteed. If you miss it, United will have to get you to Berlin some other way: most likely they would put on the  the next day flight.

Comment: Note that the OP has stated that he will have checked luggage