# travelling from India to United States via Oman

Tags: indian-citizens, transit-visas, etihad, oman, indigo

As the title suggests, I'm travelling from India to United States via Oman. My itinerary is as stated below:

AMD to BOM (IndiGo)

BOM to MCT (IndiGo)

(self transfer of luggage and layover of about 6 hrs in MCT)

MCT to AUH (Etihad)

AUH to ORD (Etihad)

I have a F-1 visa (student visa for United States)

Do I need to have a visa of Oman too? I tried contacting the airlines, but they weren't able to answer the question specifically and my dad thinks that a visa is necessary as I have to collect the luggage in arrival, leave the airport, and go to departures. I'm not sure if its needed or not, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You basically have two trips - India to Oman, and Oman to USA. Note that in case your India-Oman flights are delayed/canceled, then you are on your own for the Oman-USA trip. You need to consider if you are willing to assume this risk.

Comment: alright! i already booked the tickets w/o considering this :")
also, what kind of visa do I need to apply for? and will there be any other issues even if I have the visa?

Comment: As to the risks of flying on multiple tickets, see [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/175298/is-2-hours-enough-for-a-connecting-flight-at-ewr-doing-bog-ewr-ber-terminal-b/175299#175299). As to your visa question: this site takes one question per question, Please ask a new question about the visa, using the "Ask Question" button at top right of the screen.

Comment: This might help: https://www.omanonlinevisa.com/requirements/evisa-for-indian/#:~:text=Is%20there%20an%20Oman%20visa,get%20a%20visa%20in%20advance.